# Increasing Cell row and chopping the data of each row in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

The Programm gathers information from an txt file and pastes it into Column A as intended.
The Programm should chop everything behind the "," including the "," if there is an "ss".
The problem is it doesn´t do that if i want to increase the cells row.
I appreciate any input.
The data that needs to be chopped looks like this:
**{"id":"99-EH-F9-92-43-p8","ss":"fiPLKh3REt8npPwI"}**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWZrP.png] (Altered)

```
Sub loeschen()

Dim sn As String
Dim mac As String
Dim Cache As String
Dim i As Integer


Dim wbExcel As Workbook, wbText As Workbook
    Dim wsExcel As Worksheet
    Set wbExcel = ThisWorkbook 'specify here which Excel file the text file’s content is to be pasted into
    Set wsExcel = wbExcel.Sheets(1) 'specify here which worksheet to use
    Set wbText = Workbooks.Open("U:\Desktop\Data.txt") 'add here the path of your text file

    wbText.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsExcel.Cells

    wbText.Close SaveChanges:=False

  i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).value <> "*"



If Mid(Cells(i, 1), 28, 2) = "ss" Then
Cache = Cells(i, 1).value
mac = Left(Cache, InStr(1, Cache, ",") - 1)

Cells(i, 1).value = mac
End If

'If Mid(ActiveCell, 28, 2) = "ss" Then
'Cache = ActiveCell.value
'mac = Left(Cache, InStr(1, Cache, ",") - 1)

'ActiveCell.value = mac
'End If


    Exit Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "U:\Desktop\SHCDataold" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsm"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the sample as text rather than a picture.

Comment: Why do you have `Exit Do` in the middle of your loop? That will stop your loop.

Comment: @SJR i updated my code, you are correct but it still doesnt work. Ill post the sample into the post as a code.

Comment: If I try that code with 2 rows it replaces both up to the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the Solution to my question.
The programm gathers all information from an .txt file and pastes it into a new Workbook. Then it goes Row by Row in Column A and Chops everything after/and ","
It saves the Workbook with an actual date and specific name and closes it.
This is my Final code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub loeschen()

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "U:\Desktop\SHC_Data" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx"

Dim sn As String
Dim mac As String
Dim Cache As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ZielArbeitsmappe As Object

Set ZielArbeitsmappe = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveWorkbook.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wbExcel As Workbook, wbText As Workbook
    Dim wsExcel As Worksheet
    Set wbExcel = ZielArbeitsmappe 'specify here which Excel file the text file’s content is to be pasted into
    Set wsExcel = wbExcel.Sheets(1) 'specify here which worksheet to use
    Set wbText = Workbooks.Open("U:\Desktop\Data.txt") 'add here the path of your text file

    wbText.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wsExcel.Cells

    wbText.Close SaveChanges:=False




  i = 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).value <> ""

If Mid(Cells(i, 1), 28, 2) = "ss" Then
Cache = Cells(i, 1).value
mac = Left(Cache, InStr(1, Cache, ",") - 1)

Cells(i, 1).value = mac
End If

    
    i = i + 1

    Loop
    
ZielArbeitsmappe.Save
ZielArbeitsmappe.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```